# System.ArgumentException: 'The specified invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-5

Starting to familiarize myself with .NET and C#.

This particular project is a Windows Forms App, and the target framework is .NET 5.0 (current).

I was able to connect to a SQL Server database, so now I am trying to show the data in a form.

I am getting the title error which is pointing to a file called `EmployeeRepository.cs`.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SQLCSHARPCRUD
{
    public class EmployeeRepository
    {
        DbProviderFactory factory;
        string provider;
        string connectionString;

        public EmployeeRepository()
        {
            provider = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["provider"];
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];

            // error happens on this line
            factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider); 
        }

        public List<Employee> GetAll()
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>();

            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                connection.Open();

                var command = factory.CreateCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "Select * From Employees;";

                using(DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        employees.Add(new Employee
                                          {
                                              Id = (int)reader["Id"],
                                              FirstName = (string)reader["FirstName"],
                                              LastName = (string)reader["LastName"],
                                              email = (string)reader["email"],
                                              userlevel = (int)reader["userlevel"]
                                          });
                    }
                }
            }

            return employees;
        }
    }
}
```

Wasn't sure if I should post the whole code.

When running the code, here is the entire error message:

> Exception Unhandled
>
> System.ArgumentException: 'The specified invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers.'

As pointed out above, the error is looking at the following piece of code:

```
factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);
```

I wasn't sure if I should post any of the other files associated with the project.  I am following a tutorial and got stuck here.

I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You should probably look into using [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) instead of System.Data.SqlClient. All the new enhancements are happening there. The API surface is largely the same. As for your current issue - why use the factory to create your connection? Why not just `new SqlConnection(connectionString);`?

Comment: I was just following this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swXmjWQTfq4  Around the 6:54 mark is where it's added.

Comment: The tutorial you picked is for .NET Framework, not .NET 5. If you want good basic .NET tutorials, I suggest [IAmTimCorey](https://www.youtube.com/user/IAmTimCorey). Anyways, my suggestions in the previous comment still apply - there's no need to use the factory here.

Comment: (deep sigh) - I wish I could just plug into the Matrix and have all of this information uploaded into my brain.  I'll check out Tim Corey tutorials to see if I have more success.  Thank you.

Comment: @mason - Many of the tutorials from IAmTimCorey seem a little dated.  This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Et2khGnrIqc was from 2017.  Would you say it's still relevant?

Comment: Most of the techniques from that video will apply. Dapper is still a solid choice. We use it at my work, and the Stack Overflow development team uses it for this site. (they created it). That tutorial was made for .NET Framework as well, so instead of pulling the connection string from the .config file, you'd want to follow a more .NET Core/.NET 5 approach of getting it from appsettings.json.